# Nvidia GPU that can play games at 1440p 144hz

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, nvidia

I plan on building a gaming PC to play FPS, racing sims and VR games. I want to know what graphics cards are capable of running those style games at it's maximum presets at 1440p 144hz. These are the parts that I currently planning on putting in the system. I would like to spend around 500-750 USD on a GPU, but don't want to skimp on a GPU's quality or performance either. I'd also like this card to be a triple fan GPU.

CPU: Intel Core i9-9900kf (Plan on OC'ing)
CPU Cooler: Be Quiet! Dark Rock Slim (with two fans, in push/pull config)
MOBO: Gigabyte Z390 Gaming X LGA1151
RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 64GB (4x16) DDR4-3000
SSD: Samsung 860 Evo 1TB M.2
HDD: Western Digital Black 6TB 7200RPM
GPU: Nvidia RTX 2070 Super
Case: Thermaltake V100 (With 5 120mm Case fans)
PSU: Corsair RMx 850W 80+ Gold

Would the Nvidia RTX 2070 Super run video games at 1440p 144FPS at settings  high/very high settings without Ray Tracing? (The reason behind that is because my family member has the RTX 2080 TI and doesn't like RT b/c it impacts framerate too much)

Comment: Maybe reconsider maximum settings. Many newer games won't run at your desired resolution and Hz (I assume you mean FPS instead of Hz), even with an RTX 2080TI. Lowering a few settings here and there is often a barely noticeable dent in image quality, but can have huge impact on FPS. Hz is usually used to classify the refresh rate of a monitor. You can run with 30FPS on a 240Hz monitor...

Comment: What I meant by maximum settings is High/Very High w/o Ray Tracing. Let me update that in my op. Yes, I menant FPS, not Hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not consistently [according to the NVIDIA specs](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/rtx-2070-super/) found at their website.  A search in their [Support Forum](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/) and also [in their knowledgebase](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/list/st/5/kw/Disable%20ray%20tracing/page/1) found no comments regarding improved performance if ray tracing is turned off.

However, Inamdar in [NVIDIA Chat Support](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/chat/chat_launch/) did say "Yes, if you use the game without ray tracing the fps and performance will increase. We can't comment about the FPS (rate). FPS **depends upon the game** and configuration. It can't be constant."

[image]

Comment: If I turned off Ray Tracing (I see it on in the benchmarks) do you know what I would get on Very High w/o RT?